# p0-Pollard implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes, c++14

I should implement p0-Pollard with C++14 and a good algorithm. How may I improve my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

template <typename T>
T gcd(T a, T b){
//    printf("step1\n");
    if(a<0) a=-a;
    if(b<0) b=-b;

    T c = 1;// -> decltype(a+b);
    while((a%2 == 0)&&(b%2 == 0)){
//        printf("step2\n");
        a=a>>1;
        b=b>>1;
        c*=2;
    }
//    printf("step3\n");
    while(a!=b){
        if(a%b==0)
            return c*b;
        if(b%a==0)
            return c*a;
        if(a%2 == 0)
            a=a>>1;
        if(a>b)
            a=(a-b);
        if(b>a)
            b=(b-a);
        if(b%2 == 0)
            b=b>>1;
    }
    return c*a;
}

template <typename T>
T fx(T x, T a, T c, T modN){
    auto tmp = (a*x*x + c)%modN;
//    assert(tmp==0); // for tested simple numbers always tmp==0
    return tmp;
}

template <typename T>
T PoPollard(T src){
    T x1=2, x2=2, a=1, c=1, d=1;
    while(d==1){
        x1=fx(x1, a, c, src);
//        std::cout << "x1 is:" << x1 << "\n";
        x2=fx(fx(x2, a, c, src), a, c, src);
//        std::cout << "x2 is:" << x2 << "\n";

        if(x2==0) return 1; // looks like when src is simple number f(f(x))==0

        if(x1==x2){
            x1=2, x2=2;
            a++;
            continue;
        }

        d=gcd(abs(x1)-abs(x2), src);
//        std::cout << "d is:" << d << "\n";
    }
    return src/d;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello gcd:" << gcd(256,16) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Testing Po-Pollard:" << PoPollard(4253) << "\n";
//    printf("Hello world! %ld\n", gcd(256,16));
//    printf("Testing Po-Pollard: %ld\n", PoPollard(4253));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  What is p0-Pollard?

Comment: I'm not familiar with english math terminology, sorry. Correct name is Pollard's rho algorithm. You can read at [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard's_rho_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

A few things strike me as fairly obvious possibilities to consider here.

#### Use functions where appropriate

> ```
> if(a<0) a=-a;
> ```

I think I'd prefer to have a separate little function to compute the absolute value.

#### Be consistent

> ```
>     while((a%2 == 0)&&(b%2 == 0)){
> //        printf("step2\n");
>         a=a>>1;
>         b=b>>1;
>         c*=2;
>     }
> ```

I'd pick either bit-oriented or mathematically-oriented operations, and use them consistently. That would mean either using shifts and bit-tests throughout:

```
 while(((a & 1) == 0) && ((b & 1) == 0)){
        a >>= 1;
        b >>= 1;
        c <<= 1;
    }
```

...or else using mathematical operators throughout:

```
 while((a % 2 == 0) && (b % 2 == 0)){
        a /= 2;
        b /= 2;
        c *= 2;
    }
```

Also note the compound assignment operators--at least in my opinion, they're much clearer than things like `A = A >> 1`. Maybe it's just a background in math, but I've never like things like `A = A + 1;` that always look to me like they're just clearly false statements.

#### Better variable names

Most of your variable names are so short they're basically meaningless--`a`, `b`, `d`, `x1`, `x2`, and so on. I'd much rather see names that made their intended use/purpose easier to understand.

#### Type checking

Although it can quickly get into extremely advanced programming, I'd at least consider adding some type-checking to your templates. Just for example, I'd guess all the templates in this code really only make sense if `T` is some integer type, not floating point, a string, etc. That being the case, it's fairly easy to add at least minimal type-checking to enforce that. One simple form of that would use `static_assert`:

```
template <typename T>
T gcd(T a, T b){
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Only integer types allowed");
```

The code almost certainly won't compile if somebody attempts (for example) to get the GCD of two strings--but with the static_assert, you're pretty much guaranteed that at least part of the error message they get will say "Only integer types allowed". Without it, they're likely to get a giant avalanche of error message telling them about things like there not being an `>>` overloaded for string and int, followed by a 5-page list of the overloads of `>>` that it considered and rejected in trying to figure out a way to compile the code.

Note: there's work in progress on a set of extensions to C++ called "Concepts" to support this a little more directly in the language. Some compilers already have experimental support, in case you want to try it.

Comment: warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of '&':
    `while((a & 1 == 0)`
right:
    `while(((a&1) == 0)`

Comment: too many parentesis.
**Type checking** - Thanks. Also add in PoPollard function

Comment: @Fedor: Oops--quite right.